# Create empty file using python

Tags: python

I'd like to create a file with path `x` using python. I've been using `os.system(y)` where `y = 'touch %s' % (x)`. I've looked for a non-directory version of `os.mkdir`, but I haven't been able to find anything. Is there a tool like this to create a file without opening it, or using system or popen/subprocess?

Comment: @LevLevitsky because I'd have to close it again :P. I have to create thousands of files, and just touching the file seems cleaner.

Comment: FYI, while using an external command for this is always bad, the proper way to execute it would be `subprocess.call(['touch', x])`

Comment: @tkbx: "clean" can mean many things to many people. For example, spawning a completely separate process thousands of times is not very clean in my opinion. Sure, on modern OS's running on modern hardware a new process can be spawned pretty quickly, but it's still a crazy amount of overhead for such a small thing.

Comment: @BryanOakley to describe emotions the best way I can, "clean" to me is the program being "truly finished", with no possibility for error. `print(x); os.mkdir(y), zint = int(z)` would be a very "clean" program in my opinion, because it's all functions that preform their task with no room for error or overhead. Something like `os.touch()` would seem "clean" to me, because however many thousands of times it runs, the workflow is the same, and it even if the script takes a year, I know the code has fulfilled it's purpose without any error margin by the end.

Comment: How do you think `touch` does its job? http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/touch.c?id=f2ef324811cef997a7a7f41c895d2fc8febfb2c7 line 134

Comment: what about `Path(path2file).expanduser().touch()`

Answer (score 577, accepted):

<strike>There is no way to create a file without opening it</strike> There is `os.mknod("newfile.txt")` (*but it requires root privileges on OSX*). The system call to create a file is actually `open()` with the `O_CREAT` flag. So no matter how, you'll always open the file.

So the easiest way to simply create a file without truncating it in case it exists is this:

```
open(x, 'a').close()
```

Actually you could omit the `.close()` since the refcounting GC of CPython will close it immediately after the `open()` statement finished - but it's cleaner to do it explicitely and relying on CPython-specific behaviour is not good either.

In case you want `touch`'s behaviour (i.e. update the mtime in case the file exists):

```
import os
def touch(path):
    with open(path, 'a'):
        os.utime(path, None)
```

You could extend this to also create any directories in the path that do not exist:

```
basedir = os.path.dirname(path)
if not os.path.exists(basedir):
    os.makedirs(basedir)
```

Comment: Looks good... "Truncate" is essentially "clear", right?

Comment: Yes, opening a file with the `w` (write) flag empties it while opening it with `a` (append) doesn't.

Comment: Refcounting closing the file immediate is not to be relied on. This is not a matter of cleanliness, as refcounting is just an implementation detail. No Python except CPython does it. Want to make your program five times faster with PyPy, or run it in a Java/.NET environment with Jython/IronPython? Well too bad you didn't close those files, now your program is leaking like a sieve ;) It's especially awful since 2.5, as `with` makes it *easier* to close the file timely (and even in the face of exceptions and circular references) **and** the code becomes clearer to boot.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Wouldn't it be better not to talk about specific behavior of CPython in all cases where the question doesn't mention this concrete implementation? :)

Comment: Moreover, most of the people we need to persuade not to do this either don't know what CPython is, or foolishly assume it's the only Python that matters. I saw the reference to CPython, but the entire sentence wasn't preachy enough for my taste :)

Comment: I wanted to overwrite a file with nothing even if it existed: `open(myfile, 'w').close()`

Comment: A better one-liner is probably `with open(filename, mode='a'): pass`

Comment: Note that a minor optimization (that removes a race condition) is to pass the file descriptor from the file you opened to `os.utime`. Just change `with open(path, 'a'): os.utime(path, None)` (and that `None` argument wasn't needed; it's set by default) to `with open(path, 'a') as f: os.utime(f.fileno())` (if you need portability, you'd have to test `if os.utime in os.supports_follow_symlinks:` and only pass the file number if that returns true). This feature relies on Python 3.3, just to be clear.

Comment: In Python 3.3 the 'x' mode was added: "open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists" https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 63):

Of course there IS a way to create files without opening. It's as easy as calling `os.mknod("newfile.txt")`.  The only drawback is that this call requires root privileges on OSX.

Comment: Great point. See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: it's also unix-only. Won't work on windows

Comment: It is the only way if you absolutely want to avoid opening the file, even though it's primary use-case is to create device files and things like that, which is probably the reason why it requires root privileges on some systems. For compatibility reasons I would always stick to the `open().close()` approach wherever possible.

Comment: @CharlieParker Because opening for writing is the way to create a file right down to the operating system's API. `pathlib` and the path-like objects are a fairly recent addition to Python and absolutely superfluous in my opinion (like most features introduced after 3.6), but yes, that will work. However, if you look at the source code, you will find that it also just calls `os.open()` followed by `os.close()` to do the deed.