# How to create a notepad file in Python?

Tags: python, file

I need to know the code to create a notepad file straight from Python.

I have been searching for it but I cant find it. My teacher said that it should create a file automatically. I tried to use:

```py
filename=raw_input("")
target = open (filename, 'a')
```

It works just fine if I don't put it into a `while` loop or an `if` statement.
As soon as I do though the whole thing blows.

I am trying to create an option menu to chose between reading or writing.

```py
def main():
   foo = open("filename.txt", "w")
   foo.write('blah-blah-blah')
   foo.close()
   main()

   if option == '2':
      def main2():
         foo = open("filename.txt", "r")
         print(foo.read())
         foo.close()
         main2()
   keepgoing=input("Enter another statement?(y or n):")
   again=input("Run simulation again?(y or n): ")
   print()

   if again!= "y":
       again=False
```

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654772/create-empty-file-using-python answers your question already. A "Notepad file" is just an empty file whose name happens to end in ".txt".

Comment: FYI, "I need the code" and "I can't figure it out" won't draw much sympathy here.  Simply ask your question, ie "Why isn't my python script creating a file?

Comment: Im not asking for sympathy. I'm asking for help. Besides i figured it out by myself.

Comment: @user3059576 not according to that code you didn't, that won't create a file

Comment: Sorry about the code block mistakes. not sure how to put them in there yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can create plain text file this way:

```
foo = open("filename.txt", "w")
foo.write('blah-blah-blah')
foo.close()
```

Comment: Might want to add a newline at the end of the string written.