# Creating empty text files with specific names in a directory

Tags: python, file

I have two directories:

```
dir = path/to/annotations
```

and

```
dir_img = path/to/images
```

The format of image names in `dir_img` is `image_name.jpg`.

I need to create empty text files in `dir` as: `image_name.txt`, wherein I can later store annotations corresponding to the images. I am using Python.

I don't know how to proceed. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

[Edit]: I tried the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654772/create-empty-file-using-python). It ran without any error but didn't create any files either.

Comment: `fp = open('your_file_name', 'w')` and immediately after `fp.close()` will make a 0-sized file

Comment: To open or create a file to write you can always use - `with open('/path/to/your_file', 'w+') as yourFile:    pass`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create empty file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654772/create-empty-file-using-python)

Comment: @GPhilo I edited my question to incorporate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module `os` to list the existing files, and then just open the file in mode `w+` which will create the file even if you're not writing anything into it. Don't forget to close your file!

```
import os
for f in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        open(os.path.join(target_dir, f.replace('.jpg', '.txt')), 'w+').close()
```

Answer (score 3):

This should create empty files for you and then you can proceed further.

```
import os
for f in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        file_path = os.path.join(target_dir, f.replace('.jpg', '.txt'))
        with open(file_path, "w+"):
            pass
```

Comment: Pardon me for not knowing the subtleties but isn't this the same answer as @Elias? Anyway, still there is no file created.

Comment: yes. I should have had a look there. 
You need to provide more details i think about environment where you are running this script. Is there any error you are getting? Otherwise there is no reason why this script should not work.

Comment: I am working on Linux 8.5 based OS, Jessie. The code runs without throwing any error. I also checked that I do have write privileges for the `target_dir`.

Comment: It worked. Turns out the mistake was on my side; I was using incorrect path. Thanks for your help.