# Using `touch` in a Windows Python File

Tags: python, windows, unix

I have a Python file running on macOS which calls touch in the following ways:

```
os.system("touch -c %s" % apicache_file)

os.system("touch -c %s" % downloadFilename)

os.system("touch -c %s" % meta_cache_file)
```

However, I need to run the script on a Windows machine. How can I modify the script or the system to allow this to be done? Otherwise, I receive the following error:

```
'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654772/create-empty-file-using-python
Using open() and other Python handlers is a more efficient way to deal with this problem since it is cross platform, unlike using os.system to call terminal commands

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just don't use shell commands. Touch can be done with platform independent `pathlib`

```
from pathlib import Path

Path("some/path/file.txt").touch()
```

Simple `open(path, "w")` would also work but path on windows would need `\` instead of `/`