# How to seek write pointer in append mode?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

I am trying to open a file read it's content and write to it by using the contents that were read earlier. I am opening the file in 'a+' mode. I can't use 'r+' mode since it won't create a file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: If you know how to solve it using `r+`, why don't precede that part with a check if the file exists using `os.path.exists()`, and [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654772/create-empty-file-using-python) it if it doesn't.

Comment: @Thymen I am doing it now, but I was wondering how can you do this. There will be some scenarios where it will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a+` will put the pointer in the end of the file.

You can save it with `tell()` for later writing.

Then use `seek(0,0)` to return to file beginning for reading.

[tell()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_tell.htm)

[seek()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm)

Comment: I can't find any documentation for these functions, can you point me to it?
Thanks.

Comment: i mistakenly called it like in C fseek and ftell. in python it is just `seek` and `tell`. added doc links

Comment: In 'a+' mode they manipulate only the read pointer. I want to control where I am writing.

Comment: There is no read pointer or write pointer. Just pointer from where read or write begins

Comment: Okay, I think I made a mistake while testing it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Default open

Using the default `a(+)` option, it is not possible, as provided in the documentation:

''mode is an optional string that specifies the mode in which the file
is opened. It defaults to 'r' which means open for reading in text
mode.  Other common values are 'w' for writing (truncating the file if
it already exists), 'x' for creating and writing to a new file, **and
'a' for appending (which on some Unix systems, means that all writes
append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position).**''

---

#### Alternative

Using the default open, this is not possible.However we can of course create our own file handler, that will create a file in `r` and `r+` mode when it doesn't exists.

A minimal working example that works exactly like `open(filename, 'r+', *args, **kwargs)`, would be:

```
import os


class FileHandler:
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='r', buffering=None, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True):
        self.filename = filename
        self.mode = mode

        self.kwargs = dict(buffering=buffering, encoding=encoding, errors=errors, newline=newline, closefd=closefd)
        if self.kwargs['buffering'] is None:
            del self.kwargs['buffering']
    def __enter__(self):
        if self.mode.startswith('r') and not os.path.exists(self.filename):
            with open(self.filename, 'w'): pass
        self.file = open(self.filename, self.mode, **self.kwargs)
        return self.file

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.file.close()
```

Now when you use the following code:

```
with FileHandler("new file.txt", "r+") as file:
    file.write("First line\n")
    file.write("Second line\n")
    file.seek(0, 0)
    file.write("Third line\n")
```

It will generate a new file `new file.txt`, when it doesn't exists, with the context:

```
Third line
Second line
```

If you would use the `open` you will receive a `FileNotFoundError`, if the file doesn't exists.

---

#### Notes

- I am only creating a new file when the mode starts with an `r`, all other files are handled as would be by the normal `open` function.
- For some reason passing `buffering=None`, directly to the `open` function crashes it with an `TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)`, therefore I had to remove it from the key word arguments if it was `None`. Even though it is the default argument according to the documentation (if any one knows why, please tell me)

#### Edit

The above code didn't handle the following cases:

```
file = FileHandler("new file.txt", "r+")
file.seek(0, 0)
file.write("Welcome")
file.close()
```

In order to support **all** of the `open` use cases, the above class can be adjusted by using `__getattr__` as follows:

```
import os


class FileHandler:
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='r', buffering=None, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True):
        self.filename = filename
        self.mode = mode

        self.kwargs = dict(buffering=buffering, encoding=encoding, errors=errors, newline=newline, closefd=closefd)
        if self.kwargs['buffering'] is None:
            del self.kwargs['buffering']

        if self.mode.startswith('r') and not os.path.exists(self.filename):
            with open(self.filename, 'w'): pass
        self.file = open(self.filename, self.mode, **self.kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.file

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.file.close()

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if hasattr(self.file, item):
            return getattr(self.file, item)
        raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__}, doesn't have the attribute {item!r}")
```