# ask to create new empty file python input name from txt

Tags: python

I need your help python code to create new file (blank) just name from a list.

```
my_list = ['jordan', 'bella', 'anabelle']
```

we want to create

1. jordan.html
2. bella.html
3. anabelle.html

thank you so much everyone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create empty file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654772/create-empty-file-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

(Edited: for importing and iterating)
if you want to iterate through a list:

```
with open('a.txt') as f:
    a = f.read().split(' ')
for i in a:
    with open(i + '.html', 'w') as f:
        pass
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want create new file in directory input name files from a.txt list

Comment: You should never use os.popen with an unescaped argument parameter just thrown in like that to do file operations (or anything else unescaped, really). This is unsafe, and one of the worst ways to do it. E.g. open() with mode "w" and closing with no content does the job without these caveats.

Comment: True, I'm still learning myself.

Comment: What would you recommend? With open(i) as f?

Comment: Yes, open() works fine. That is a built-in python function and doesn't use the system shell, so it doesn't have any of the escaping caveats that os.popen() or os.system() do. Shells in general are a programming language of their own, and it is better not to use them with untrusted input unless you really need to.

Comment: Well thanks for the tip!! I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("names.txt") as f:
    my_list = f.readline().split()
    for item in my_list:
        with open(item+'.html', 'w') as fp:
            pass
```

Comment: Maybe you'd want to incorporate `with open("names.txt") as f` with `f.readline().split()` from one of the other responses instead of the hardcoded list contents? That might make for a nice, complete response

Comment: Good comment. Thank's.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os


class IO:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = open("names.txt").readline().split()

    def show(self):
        return self.data

    def create_files(self):
        for i in self.data:
            os.system("touch " + str(i) + str(".html"))


io = IO()

print(io.create_files())
```

Try this....and in names.txt just put blank space between names

Comment: Very unsafe, don't combine shell commands with unescaped user arguments like that, ever. This allows arbitrary code execution with malicious file name inputs.

Comment: yea, but its for  a  newbie who wont deploy it and it is just for practice "proof of work" written under one minute.. I understand what you say and I agree, but context here allow it

Comment: I would suggest it's not a good idea to teach anyone, including newcomers, such bad practices when this is so incredibly insecure and the correct safe approach (see other response https://stackoverflow.com/a/65717764/1204141 ) is comparatively simple to do. Please don't make anyone use shell commands without escaping.