# Python - function to write multiple files with loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that would use a loop to write multiple files, but it's not succeeding. Here are the code, and the result. The directory does exist; I was able to write, read, and append single files to it with no problem. This was done in the ordinary Python 3.9 interactive command line window on Windows 10.

```
def writepages(i):
    for j in range(i):
        name = f"0{j}0page.html"
        file = open(f'C:\\Users\\cumminjm\\Documents\\{name}', 'r+')
        file.close()

>>>
>>> writepages(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in writepages
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\cumminjm\\Documents\\000page.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `"w"` or `"a"`, `"r+"` requires that the file already exist; it does not create the file if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different [file mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) — such as:

- `w` to open a (possibly new) file, and empty it if it exists.
- `a` to open a (possibly new) file, but not empty it.
- `x` to open a new file **and fail with `FileExistsError` if it exists**.

As [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) pointed out, `r+` opens an **existing** file for read and write.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654772/create-empty-file-using-python/12654798) you can also use `os.mknod("newfile.txt")`, but it requires root privilege on macOS.

It's a bit off-topic, but you might like to know about `pathlib`, which gives you an OS-agnostic way to handle file paths, and using a context for the file opening, which is safer than `open`/`close`. Here's how I'd probably write that function:

```
import pathlib

def writepages(i):
    """Write i HTML pages."""
    for j in range(i):
        fname = pathlib.Path.home() / 'Documents' / f'0{j}0page.html'
        with open(fname, 'x') as f:
            f.write('')
    return
```